# Why is it important to have disjoint sets in a union for the union to make sense w.r.t the order types?

Tags: set-theory

This question has been bugging me for quite some time now.

Say we have some $\beta$ smaller than some $\gamma$ and a sequence

$\beta$<sub>$\epsilon$</sub> : $\epsilon$ smaller than cf($\beta$) cofinal in $\beta$ and say

we have some sets $A$<sub>n</sub><sup>$\epsilon$</sup> and each of these $A$<sub>n</sub><sup>$\epsilon$</sup> has order type less than $\gamma$<sup>$n$</sup>.

Now $\forall n$ in $\omega$ let $B$<sub>n</sub>= $\cup$ $A$<sub>n</sub><sup>$\epsilon$</sup> for all $\epsilon$ < $\gamma$ and suppose in the end I can write $\beta$ as the union of all the $B$<sub>n</sub> (but that is not really my problem here)

Why can I deduce that $B$<sub>n</sub> has order type less than $\gamma$<sup>$n+1$</sup> ***only if*** all my sets $A$<sub>n</sub><sup>$\epsilon$</sup> are disjoint and do not overlap?

(since we have a union of less then $\gamma$ sets each of which is of order type less than $\gamma$<sup>$n$</sup>)

Why can't I still guarantee that the $B$<sub>n</sub> will still have order type $\gamma$<sup>$n+1$</sup> if all the $A$<sub>n</sub><sup>$\epsilon$</sup> are not disjoint?

I know that I need to take the $A$<sub>n</sub><sup>$\epsilon$</sup> to be [$\epsilon$,$\epsilon+1$) so that they are disjoint.

But why does everything in the union have to be in order?

I hope I conveyed my question clearly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say so, but you are speaking of ordinals here and ordinal exponentiation.

The problem is that if you take the union of sets not in order, then you can't control the order type. Let me give an easy example to illustrate the point. Suppose that A<sub>n</sub> for each n < ω consists of a single ordinal. If the ordinal of A<sub>n</sub> is below the ordinal of A<sub>m</sub> whenever n < m, then the union set U<sub>n</sub> A<sub>n</sub> will clearly have order type ω. But if I drop that requirement, then I can get any countable ordinal at all! That is, every set is the uion of its singletons. In particular, if α is a countable ordinal, then α = U { {β} | β < α} is the union of countably many one point orders. Indeed, if you go to the non-ordinal context, then every countable order type, such as Q, is the union of countably many singletons.

A similar problem arises in your specific question. You can't guarrantee that the union of the A<sub>n</sub><sup>ε</sup> has small order type, if you allow them to get mixed up all together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me see if I understood it. Let's choose in disorder some of your $A_n$ sets: $A_1$ is $\omega+1$ , $A_2$ is 5, $A_3$ be $\omega$. When I take the union the o.t is $\omega$+6+$\omega$ . Is this true? Same for the $A_n^{\epsilon}$ : if I do not take them in order, I can choose $\gamma^{2n}$ for the first one (1 element in this set so its o.t is 1!), 5 for the second one, $\gamma$ for the 3rd one, but when I take the union I get to something way bigger than $\gamma^{n+1}$. But the bound is $\gamma^+$.

Comment: Not quite. With your A1, A2 and A3, the union is just omega+1, since your A2 and A3 are subsets of A1. You would get omega+6+omega (which is = omega+omega, or omega*2) if you had A1=omega, A2=[omega,omega+5], and A3=[omega+5,omega+omega). This would be the disjoint case, and where the sets appear in disjoint intervals that are spaced out in the same order as the indices. In my answer, I had very tiny order types for each An, but the union had huge order type. But you are right in your last sentence, that gamma+ is still a bound, and this is a cardinality calculation.

Comment: I see. With your choice the o.t of $A_1$ is $\omega$, that of $A_2$ is 6 ($A_2$ has $\omega$, $\omega$+1, $\omega$+2, $\omega$+3, $\omega$+4, $\omega$+5, so 6 elements) and $A_3$ has $\omega$ elements. But say I had $A_1$ is {$\omega$}, $A_2$ is {$\omega$, $\omega$+5} and $A_3$ is {$\omega$+5, $\omega$+$\omega$+}, these sets respectively have 1 element, 2 elements and 2 elements, but their union has 3 elements so it is {$\omega$, $\omega$+5, $\omega$+$\omega$} so the o.t is 3. It seems to me that we would just be adding all these elements by juxtaposition. 

Comment: I was thinking that I had to lay down on the table $\omega$ things and then $\omega$+5 in front of it and then $\omega$+$\omega$ things in front of what I had put in the table at the previous step, but I was wrong...It would have been the case if that was the width of some intervals. 
 

Comment: I feel like what I've said previously is mostly nonsense. 
If $A_1$ is [$\omega+1$,$\omega+5$) and $A_2$ is [$\omega+5$,$\omega$+$\omega$) and $A_3$ is [0,6] then the union of $A_1$,$A_2$ and $A_3$ in this order is $\omega+7$.
But if I take the union of $A_3$, $A_1$, $A_2$ in this order then I only get $\omega$.
Now I think I got it right. I hope...

Comment: I don't quite follow you. The union operation on sets is commutative; it doesn't matter what the order is. Perhaps you have in mind the idea of ordinal addition, where one puts a copy of each set into a separate block, in order to make them disjoint, and then takes the disjoint union of these sets (that is, the ordinary union of disjoint copies of the sets). When one defines alpha+beta, it means a copy of alpha followed by a copy of beta, and it is in this sense that is used. In contrast alpha union beta is simply the larger of the two ordinals.

Comment: Please bear with me because this is the heart of the problem that is bothering me: if the union operation is commutative then how can the order matter? Why shouldn't we just take the largest order type for the union and not care if the sets are disjoint or not?

Comment: The sets A_n are subsets of some larger ambient order. For example, in the construction of your question, I took the sets A_n^epsilon to be sets of ordinals, which have their own order. The main question is: if you know the order types of a bunch of sets A_n, what can you say about the order type of their union? It doesn't matter what order you take the union in, since union is a commutative operation. But if the A_n each have some order type, and they are subsets of intervals or blocks in the ordinals, then the union of the A_n will have an order type that behaves well. But if you allow...

Comment: ...them to mix together, then the example in my answer shows that the order type of the union can be very larger indeed. 

Comment:  So if I take all the A_n to be the same set consisting of the same ordinal, say it is omega+7, then the union for all n will be omega+7 and so will be the order type (it'll be bigger than omega. But what if I take for the first five sets A_1 to A_5 omega+n and then for A_6 to A_10 omega+n-1 etc...?What happens here? Thank you so much for your help.